# creating a scheduled Job in laravel 10 using database driver

Tags: laravel, queue, driver, jobs

first i used the database as my driver by adding it in `.env` file
I created the job and defined the table (product) and the row (status) to change it from zero to one in the handle method
then i dispatched it in the index function in my controller with a delay of a minute and it worked well after i run `php artisan queue:work` but i thought it's not the right thing to do

I tried to use scheduling task by adding the logic in the schedule function in the `console/kernel.php`

it only works when i run `php artisan schedule:run`

i tried to use Task Schedular to make it run `php artisan schedule:run` every 1 minute but it's not working so I checked the logs it says that

`"[previous exception] [object] (PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel-project.jobs' doesn't exist at C:\\Users\\Youmna\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\project\\laravel-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php:416)"`

but the table is already in my phpmyadmin i tries to clear all the cache but it's not working so i tried to drop the table and migrate it again but still not working

code:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule): void
{
    // $schedule->command('inspire')->hourly();
    $schedule->job(new StatusJob)->everyMinute();

}

protected function commands(): void
{
    $this->load(__DIR__ . '/Commands');

    require base_path('routes/console.php');
}

public function __construct()
{
   
}
public function handle(): void
{
    
    DB::table('products')->where('status', 0)->update(['status' => 1]);
}
```

`return new class extends Migration {`
`public function up(): void`
`{`
`Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {`
`$table->id();`
`$table->string('name');`
`$table->text('description');`
`$table->float('price');`
`$table->boolean('status')->default(0);`
`$table->timestamps();`
`});`
`}`
`` };` ``

I run `php artisan queue:restart` didn't fix it and `php artisan queue:failed` show no faild jobs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkoPn.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zduAY.png)

how to solve this please

Comment: You need to run `php artisan queue:table` and than `php artisan migrate` to create jobs table automatically. queue:table create migration for you

Comment: already done but nothing happen i tried to php artisan migrate:rollback and migrate it agian but the error still exist and i cleared the cache also

Comment: does it create the jobs table?

Comment: yes and it created it in my phpmyadmin 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkoPn.png

Answer (score 0):

@Youmna, I'm sharing the migration file here, you can put it manually and run migration and verify the JOBS table is created

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateJobsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('jobs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('queue')->index();
            $table->longText('payload');
            $table->unsignedTinyInteger('attempts');
            $table->unsignedInteger('reserved_at')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedInteger('available_at');
            $table->unsignedInteger('created_at');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('jobs');
    }
}
```

Comment: already done but it's not working thanks for your help